# Small connector alternative for 10/100base Ethernet

Tags: connector, ethernet, rj45, industrial

I have been looking for a small connector that I can use for Ethernet 10/100 base communication. There were some similar discussions here about the same topic, but I couldn't find a solid answer.

In my application, I don't want to use an RJ45 connector because of the form factor. I looked at some industrial connectors like "Industrial Mini IO" from TE, but the problem with those is now I have to deal with a big back shell for the cable itself although the connector helps with making the product smaller.

https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-2294417-4.html

I was wondering has anyone used an RJ12 for a 10/100 base Ethernet application? That's currently one of the options I'm looking at and I'm not sure if it is the correct way.

If RJ12 is not a good option, does anyone know any small connector that I can use which also doesn't need a big back shell for the mating cable?